# Unable to execute JavaScript with PhantomJSDriver with ckeditor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I try to set the content of a CKeditor inside a Selenium Test.

```
public void setCkEditorContent(String html) {
    WebDriver webDriver = getDriver();
    webDriver.switchTo().frame(ckEditorIframe);
    WebElement cKEditorBody = webDriver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
    JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
    String script = "arguments[0].innerHTML = \"" + html + "\" ;";
    javascriptExecutor.executeScript(script, cKEditorBody);
    webDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

This is my code but it did not work with the PhantomJSDriver. The Content of the CKeditor is not set with the `javascriptExecutor`. Also not if I send the content with `ckeditorbody.sendKeys(text)`.
With the ChromeDriver everything is fine but not with the PhantomJsDriver.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you try with different selector? not the `body` tag

Comment: Yes I try to select the p-Tag inside body, but also doesn't work.